# Angular split screen in vs code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I would love to have an extension in vs code that would open both ts code and HTML template at the same time (preferably in split-screen) whenever I click on `*.ts`/`*.html` file.

Do you someone know about such extension? (or another way how to achieve this behaviour)

Thanks for any answer :)

Comment: You can right click an open file tab and you will see the options "Split Up", "Split Down", "Split Left" and "Split Right". Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found such extension in the marketplace: [chifilly.angular-split](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chifilly.angular-split)

Just press alt-S to open component template, style and code (possible to configure) at the same time in the split view.

Answer (score 0):

With the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v0.11.0 and the command `htmlRelatedLinks.openFile` you can construct the file to open:

Create the following keybindings : (choose any key combo you like)

The key combo is the same for both definitions:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i r",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.html",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": "split"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == typescript"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i r",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.ts",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": "split"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html"
  }
```

Based on the languageId of the current file we choose a different file extension.

The `"viewColumn": "split"` makes the file open in the other column ( 1 or 2 ), the new file does not get the focus and it is not a preview file.